# Validation of Error message preceded with image using Selenium Webdriver Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

Please help me to get the Error message.

```
<div id="divDraftErrorMessages" data-ng-show="showDraftErrorMessage()" class="alert alert-danger">
  <div data-ng-repeat="message in draftErrorMessages" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
    <img src="../../Images/alert.gif" alt="Error Message">
 Invalid Keyword
   </div>
</div>
```

I tried with below code but message is printed. Observed failure.

```
String message = driver.findElement(By.className("ng-binding ng-scope")).getText();
System.out.println(message);
```

I am struggling as error message is preceded with image. Please help.

The error I get is

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Selenium only allows a single class name, so you can't use `"ng-binding ng-scope"` as your class selector. You can only use one of the two classes.

I'd suggest starting by getting the outer div by ID since you have an ID to work with. If the inner div is the only div that will display, you can then use `findElement(By.tagName("div")).getText();` to retrieve the text.

If that gives you the image HTML as well as the text (it shouldn't), you can use a simple substring function to keep only the text after the `>`.

So your code should do something like:

```
outerdiv = driver.findElement(By.id("divDraftErrorMessages"));
message = outerdiv.findElement(By.tagName("div")).getText();
```

Answer (score 2):

`ng-binding` and `ng-scope` are 2 different classes. Compound classes are not supported by class selector in selenium. You can use the xpath if want to access the element based on more then one class like below :-

```
String message = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ng-binding ng-scope']")).getText();
System.out.println(message);
```

or can be CSS Selector as :

```
String message = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.ng-binding.ng-scope")).getText();
System.out.println(message);
```